# PGFPlots append text to all contour labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is it possible to append a text suffix (in my case a unit) to all labels in a PGFPlots contour plot?

For example, consider the following plot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view = {0}{90}]
\addplot3[
    contour gnuplot={
        draw color=black,
        contour label style={every node/.append style={text=black}},
%       somehow append "ms" to all labels
    },
    samples=50
] {x^2+y};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I imagine it to look like the following:

[image: PGFPlots contour plot with label suffixes]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the label contents using the `contour/label node code/.code` key:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/relative round mode=fixed}
\pgfplotsset{
    contour/label node code/.code={%
        \node{\pgfmathprintnumber{#1}\,ms};%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view = {0}{90}]
\addplot3[
    contour gnuplot={
        draw color=black,
        contour label style={
            every node/.append style={text=black}
        }
    },
    samples=50
] {x^2+y};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```